RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded | [Previous line repeated 972 more times] | socket.io
I need help that why i am getting error like RecursionError, i am using the python-socket
BTW before moving ahead i want to make it clear that this issue is not because of socket configuration it is working fine the simple test events work fine.
Here is my socket event that listen to specific event:
@sio_server.on(EVENT.REPLY_ON_TICKET)
async def reply_on_ticket_event(sid:str, data:dict):
    
    sender_id = None
    if data["sender_info"]["sender_id"]:
        sender_id= data["sender_info"]["sender_id"]
    else:
        sender_id= data["sender_id"]
        
    payload = {
        "ticket_id": data["ticket_id"],
        "sender_id": sender_id,
        "notify": data["notify"],
        "reply": data["reply"],
    }
    # Obtain a database session manually
    db_session = next(get_db())
    res = await reply_on_ticket_service(payload, db_session)
    if res["success"]:
        # the callback data for client socket
        return {
                    "status_code": 200,
                    "success": True,
                    "message": "reply data",
                    "payload": res["data"],
                }
    
    return {"status_code": 400, "success": False}  

  


and here the service that handle the reply tickets process:

async def reply_on_ticket_service(data:dict, db_session: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    try:
        new_reply= TicketReplyModal(reply_text=data["reply"],ticket_id=data["ticket_id"],sender_id=data["sender_id"])
        
        new_reply_id= await db_manager.add_record(new_reply,db_session)
        if not new_reply_id:
            return {"success":False, 'status_code':400, "message":"Error occurred while creating new replay"} 
        new_record= await db_manager.get_record_by_id(new_reply_id, TicketReplyModal,db_session)
        if not new_record:
            return {"success":False, 'status_code':404, "message":"Unable to find record with newly created replay"} 
            
        sender_data = db_session.query(UserModel).filter(UserModel.id == new_record.sender_id).first()
        if not sender_data:
            return {"success":False, 'status_code':404, "message":"Unable to find sender info"} 
        
        reply = {
            "id":new_record.id,
            "created_at":new_record.created_at,
            "reply_text":new_record.reply_text,
            "ticket_id": new_record.ticket_id,
            "sender":{
                "id": sender_data.id,
                "email": sender_data.email,
                "profile_image": sender_data.profile_image,
                "username": sender_data.username,
                "public_key": sender_data.public_key,
            }

        }
        
        return {"success": True, "data": reply}
        

    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=str(e))
    


in reply_on_ticket_event return method if i comment the line "payload": res["data"] and then it works fine without any issue:
Error code-snippet:
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-39' coro=<AsyncServer._handle_event_internal() done, defined at C:\Users\AK\.virtualenvs\BE-hVO0_cLf\Lib\site-packages\socketio\async_server.py:605> exception=RecursionError('maximum recursion depth exceeded')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AK\.virtualenvs\BE-hVO0_cLf\Lib\site-packages\socketio\async_server.py", line 617, in _handle_event_internal
    await server._send_packet(eio_sid, self.packet_class(
  File "C:\Users\AK\.virtualenvs\BE-hVO0_cLf\Lib\site-packages\socketio\async_server.py", line 518, in _send_packet
    encoded_packet = pkt.encode()
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\AK\.virtualenvs\BE-hVO0_cLf\Lib\site-packages\socketio\packet.py", line 64, in encode
    encoded_packet += self.json.dumps(data, separators=(',', ':'))
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\json\encoder.py", line 200, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\json\encoder.py", line 258, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\BE\app.py", line 38, in default
    return super().default(obj)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\BE\app.py", line 38, in default
    return super().default(obj)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\BE\app.py", line 38, in default
    return super().default(obj)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  [Previous line repeated 972 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

And the line to whom the error is pointing is in app.py
class CustomJSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, uuid.UUID):
            return str(obj)
        return super().default(obj)
    

@app.on_event("startup")
def startup_event():
    json.JSONEncoder.default = CustomJSONEncoder().default

I try to comment the above @app.on_event("startup") and then execute that socket event then the error complaining about  UUID here is the error output:
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-47' coro=<AsyncServer._handle_event_internal() done, defined at C:\Users\AK\.virtualenvs\pw7-BE-hVO0_cLf\Lib\site-packages\socketio\async_server.py:605> exception=TypeError('Object of type UUID is not JSON serializable')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AK\.virtualenvs\pw7-BE-hVO0_cLf\Lib\site-packages\socketio\async_server.py", line 617, in _handle_event_internal
    await server._send_packet(eio_sid, self.packet_class(
  File "C:\Users\AK\.virtualenvs\pw7-BE-hVO0_cLf\Lib\site-packages\socketio\async_server.py", line 518, in _send_packet
    encoded_packet = pkt.encode()
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\AK\.virtualenvs\pw7-BE-hVO0_cLf\Lib\site-packages\socketio\packet.py", line 64, in encode
    encoded_packet += self.json.dumps(data, separators=(',', ':'))
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\json\encoder.py", line 200, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\json\encoder.py", line 258, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\json\encoder.py", line 180, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type UUID is not JSON serializable


Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text (formatted as code) in the question. You may shorten it if too many repeated lines appear.

@MichaelButscher added you can check it now

The issue you have is with this line:
json.JSONEncoder.default = CustomJSONEncoder().default

This replaces the default method in JSONEncoder with a custom version originally written for your CustomJSONEncoder subclass. However, that subclass version calls super(), which looks up the implementation in its base class. The base class is JSONEncoder, so after you do the method replacement, it ends up finding itself. Thus, when you have an unencodable value, you don't get the expected TypeError, you get recursion until you hit the limit and get a RecursionError.
As for how to fix the issue, I think there are two options. One way to fix the immediate symptom would be to replace the call to super().default(obj) with an explicit raise TypeError call (with perhaps a message that describes the object that couldn't be encoded).
However, other than letting you find whatever bogus data is triggering the issue, this doesn't really fix underlying jankyness of the method replacement. Another option would be to figure out how to properly pass your CustomJSONEncoder class to your library framework so that it will use it instead of the original encoder from the standard library. That way you can continue to write your own default method in the recommended style, without breaking things by replacing json.JSONEncoder.default.
